# MVVM pattern implementation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I want use `MVVM pattern` in the WP app. I have a some idea about this pattern. But I do not understand some things. I do not know whether it's good practice or not to do so.

So, I have `Model`.
Model is a data structure. The set of fields and properties.

**Model**

```
 public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private GeoCoordinate coordinate;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public GeoCoordinate Coordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.coordinate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.coordinate != value)
            {
                this.coordinate = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Coordinate");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel initializes the fields of the model.

**ViewModel**

```
 public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Person User
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }        

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
           this.User = new Person();
        }  

        public LoadData()
        {
           Service.GetUser((result) => 
            {
                 this.User.Name = result.Name;
                 this.User.Coordinate = result.Coordinate;
            });

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
PersonViewModel _viewModel;
this.DataContext = _viewModel;
_viewModel.LoadData();
```

Here are the moments that I would like to clarify:

1. How can  ViewModel notify View about error in loading data, end loading?
2. Can I pass part of date to View (without databinding, technically it is possible, I mean, this is permissible under the pattern)?

For exaple, in **ViewModel**:

```
   public LoadData(Action<Person, Exception> act)
            {
               Service.GetUser((result, error) => 
                {
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        act.Invoke(null, error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.User.Name = result.Name;
                        this.User.Coordinate = result.Coordinate;
                        act.Invoke(result, null);
                    }
                });                   
            }
```

In **View**:

```
_viewModel.LoadData((result, error) =>
    { 
       if (error != null)
       {
             //error data loading
       }
       else
       {
            //successfully loading
       }
    });
```

This is terrible, probably this approach destroys the whole concept. But, for example, I   work with `Jeff Wilcox` static map.

```
           <jwMaps:StaticMap                                
                            Provider="Bing"                                                                   
                            Visibility="Visible">
                            <jwMaps:StaticMap.MapCenter>
                                <geo:GeoCoordinate 
                                    Latitude ="50"
                                    Longitude="50" />
                            </jwMaps:StaticMap.MapCenter>
                        </jwMaps:StaticMap>
```

I can't binding coordinate to this control. I tried, dont't work. If use

```
 StaticMap.MapCenter =
       new GeoCoordinate() { Latitude = user.Latitude, Longitude = user.Longitude };
```

then works.

In the case of a delegate I could do it in a successfully branch...

Please help advice.

Comment: You probably want to start with an MVVM framework, otherwise you end up writing a lot of plumbing code to make stuff work - and without much experience on the pattern you are likely to make mistakes that other people have already solved. I'm not saying you shouldn't try to understand it, but I am saying that it's already understood, and there are a fair few differing ways to implement the pattern. One of my favourite MVVM frameworks is Caliburn Micro which works for WP7 (and probably WP8 though I've not checked out the latest version).

Comment: Just checked and yes it supports WP8. Try a couple out like MVVM Light, Prism, and Caliburn Micro - http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com

Comment: For the binding issue - it sounds like the control you are speaking about doesn't support the bindings. That's more an issue with the control, but you could work around it by using the Event Aggregator (or an implementation of the Mediator pattern) - basically you subscribe to messages of a certain type in your View and send messages of that type from your ViewModel. Your mediator sits in the middle and receives messages, delegating them to subscribers. This way you can replace either end of the message chain as they are not dependent on each other

Comment: Thank you! I checked Caliburn Micro, I opened some examples, so far it's magic for me. :) So many classes in the namespace Caliburn, it requires study. I have seen in the examples Event Aggregator, think understand the idea, I like this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send messages from your **viewmodel** to your **view** for that you can use **Messenger class** of mvvm light.

And i will not broke the **MVVM pattern** Because What **MVVM** pattern is that you have to do your logic part in **ViewModel** but it does not mean that you can not use Your Page.xaml.cs Code behind.you can make decisions on visibility or any **UI** related Code in your Code behind.Also it is not a Hard Coded Pattern actually it is made to organize your project in much better and simpler way but if you have to communicate between **view** and your **viewModel** for some Reason that you can not solve from viewmodel than you can use you codebehind.
I am not an expert but this is what i think..hope some updates on this topic..